# Visual Studio 2015: x64 vs x86 for running app in emulator?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, uwp, visual-studio-cordova

I'm running Windows10 Pro fresh install, Visual Studio 2015 fresh instal with UWP, WP8 SDKS and Cordova tools instaled. Hyper-V is enabled. According to Control Panel, my processor is an Intel Core i7 with x64 architecture.

I'm trying to run the HelloWord Cordova project on a Windows phone emulator (Windows10, tried various devices). Surprisingly, it works when I select `x86`, but if I choose `x64`, I get the following error: `bootstrapper could not connect to machine`

Still, even after deploying `x86` app to emulator, I get other problems in some rare cases (trying to declare a share target and trying to share Edge link to my app crashes WWAHost.exe), so if possible I'd like to try `x64` to see if it solves these problems as well (probably not, as I got same problem on device HP Elite X3/ARM).

Can someone explain me why my processor is supposed to be `x64` and that I can't deploy my app to the emulator actually only works by selecting `x86`?

Comment: Please instead of downvoting it would be helpful to explain why. Yes I'm a Windows newbie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can someone explain me why my processor is supposed to be x64 and that I can't deploy my app to the emulator actually only works by selecting x86?

It's because the Virtualization is x86 (It's a x86 virtualized system). You can find it under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\<VersionNumber>\XDE.exe`.

Task Manager:
[image]

And when you are deploying the app to the Emulator, you are actually deploying your app to the x86 virtualized system. So it won't work if you select x64.

Comment: Hmmm I see, so you mean that the emulator runs in Hyper-V virtualization system and it's x86 right?

Comment: I mean the Emulator's system image that runs in Hyper-V is x86. And currently there is no x64 version.